# How/where do I upload a (python) script to jenkins to run?

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to execute a script via the "execute shell" build section of my build's configuration

```
sudo python buildscript.py param1 param2
```

however I don't know how/where to actually upload the script. Hope this makes sense, I don't have shell access to the Jenkins server (or I would put it in the workspace directory I'm guessing) so I'm wondering if there's an upload interface that I missed somewhere.

Comment: If you haven't been granted shell access, it's unlikely you were granted sudo rights on that machine. You might have a problem with that if your script does require using `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a project on your version control system to keep all your scripts. Then, just create a job on jenkins to fetch them (dont need to build anything). They will be made available on the filesystem, inside ~jenkins/workspace, and everytime you change them, Jenkins will make sure they keep up-to-date on the build machine.

For sudo, you need to have ssh access (or know who has) as @Bruno suggested, and grant jenkins user that permission.

Answer (score 1):

You should just put `buildscript.py` in version control next to your source files -- I assume you already have an action configured in your job config to checkout your sources from version control?